# generate slug field for an existing data in database

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, slug

i am using laravel and phpmyadmin and i need to add slug field for like 12K entries in my database .

i tried using a route to update the empty 'slug' column with slug data :

```
Route::get('/slug', function(){


$needSlugs = entreprise::where('slug', '')->get();

foreach($needSlugs as $slug){
    $slug->update([
        'slug' => Str::slug($slug->RS)
    ]);
}});
```

but it takes so much time and it returns an error after slugging about 400 columns and i need to start again and it will take me hours to finish, i searched a lot and didn't find a good solution for my case .

any good way to do it please !!

PS : i am using the sluggable-eloquent package to slug any new saved data in the DB .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12K rows is nothing. It usually should take only seconds to complete, there might be other reason why it doesn't completes
Probably it's because gateway time out or other constraints on your server.
Try running it using `php artisan tinker`, and also try to chunk your records.

```sh
$ php artisan tinker
```

```php
App\Models\entreprise::where('slug', '')->chunk(500, function($recs){
  $recs->map(function($record){
    $record->update([
      'slug' => Str::slug($record->RS)
    ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: so what does chunk do exactly !!

Comment: it worked perfectly, i just wanna ask you if i wanna do the same thing on a live website because obviously this method works only on the local machine !!

Comment: It's all about server limitations. Memory or max_execution_time. (Write error to see which one has problem) . You have to increase one of them (or both) to run this code on production. But I don't recomend doing that on production server

Comment: and how can i do the same thing to my live database !!

Comment: You have to run This query in your live database, edit `.env` db config with live credentials and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$needSlugs = entreprise::whereNull('slug')->update(["slug"=> DB::raw("replace(trim(lower(RS)), ' ', '-')")]);
```

Note:Keep backup for safty purpose if its genuine data